# Fairness Monitor Doesn't Allow Configuration of "Maximum Records"

Tags: watson-openscale

When configuring accuracy monitor, one can specify min records and max records for metric computation; however, when configuring fairness monitor, there is only min records, and effectively it seems to be the fixed number of rows for fairness computation. Can anyone explain why fairness monitor is designed differently from accuracy monitor on this aspect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`min_records` in the fairness configuration is basically the minimum sample size of the data that needs to be read from the payload logging table every hour to compute the fairness on. If there are fewer records than the specified `min_records` then the fairness computation would not be performed and the previous metrics would be copied as there wasn't enough data to make sense out of the fairness computation.

Given we have >= `min_records` which were added in the last hour (since last time when fairness was computed) we will read the last `min_records` number of records and compute the fairness values on them. We would also de-bias any bias (if present) and show the de-biased behavior of the model.